# Confused with an relative clause in active and passive form

Tags: grammar

I want to say

> I like eggs that are boiled in 7 minutes.

My attempt is as follows but I am not sure which correct.

> A: 七分煮た卵が好きです。
>
> B: 七分煮られた卵が好きです。

How to make an relative clause in passive form?

Comment: +1, but [茹]{ゆ}でる ＞ [煮]{に}る for boiling eggs.

Comment: Since there's no adjective in the clause in question, "adjective clause" seems like an inappropriate term.  "Adjective" is a type of word, not a function. How about "relative clause"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"l'électeur" is right: we use 茹でる for boiling eggs.

So I recommend that you write 七分茹でた卵が好きです。

For the record,  七分茹でられた卵が好きです。 is *not* syntactically incorrect, but we don't say that.